# Check if a word is enclosed within quotes using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have a string like `get(3,"No MATCH",obj)`. I want to check if the word MATCH is enclosed within quotes (either single quote or double quote). Here MATCH is enclosed within quotes, although not exactly as "MATCH", it is still a part of the text contained in quotes as "No MATCH". 

I want to write a function which takes the word (MATCH) as argument and returns true if it is contained within quotes or false if not.
Following are some other input strings which needs to be checked by this 
function:
* `get(1101,"MATCH",obj)` --> return true since MATCH is within quotes
* `get(255,'NO MATCH',obj)` --> return true since MATCH is a part of text contained within quotes
* `get(1111,"" , MATCH)` ---> return false since MATCH is not contained within quotes

Comment: To clarify is `get(3,"No MATCH",obj)` *text* or is it a function call?

Comment: Any reason not searching with quotes itself  `get(1101,"\"MATCH\"",obj)` ?

Comment: @VLAZ, it is a string only, a text. Not a function call.

Comment: @kiranvj if I search using quotes, is says true as "get(1101,"MATCH",obj)" is itself contained within quotes, as it is treated as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is for refactoring, so this should do

- no mismatching quotes (maybe except ill stuff like 'MAT\'CH' or 'MAT' + 'CH'
- single or double quotes

Left handled cases can be handled by hand

```js
const inString = s => line => {
  const has = [...line.matchAll(/'[^']*'/g)].find(x => x[0].includes(s))
  return has || [...line.matchAll(/"[^"]*"/g)].find(x => x[0].includes(s))
}
const matcher = inString('MATCH')
console.log(matcher('get(1101,"MATCH",obj)'))
console.log(matcher("get(255,'YES MATCH',obj)"))
console.log(matcher('get(1111,"" , NO MATCH)')) // not in quotes
console.log(matcher('get(1111,"" , "NO MATCH\')')) // no mismatching quotes
console.log(matcher("get('a',NO MATCH , 'b')")) // wrapped by matching quotes does not match
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this

https://regex101.com/r/Bu4LUO/2

```
/['"]([ \w]+)?MATCH([ \w]+)?["']/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to perform syntactic analysis you should consider using [esprima](https://esprima.org/)

This is the AST returned by

```js
esprima.parse(`get(1111,"" , MATCH)`);
```

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ExpressionStatement",
      "expression": {
        "type": "CallExpression",
        "callee": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "name": "get"
        },
        "arguments": [
          {
            "type": "Literal",
            "value": 1111,
            "raw": "1111"
          },
          {
            "type": "Literal",
            "value": "",
            "raw": "\"\""
          },
          {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "name": "MATCH"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "script"
}
```

And here's for

```js
esprima.parse(`get(255,'NO MATCH',obj)`)
```

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ExpressionStatement",
      "expression": {
        "type": "CallExpression",
        "callee": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "name": "get"
        },
        "arguments": [
          {
            "type": "Literal",
            "value": 255,
            "raw": "255"
          },
          {
            "type": "Literal",
            "value": "NO MATCH",
            "raw": "'NO MATCH'"
          },
          {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "name": "obj"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "script"
}
```

You can search a 'Literal' type which value includes 'MATCH'.

```js
const matcher = code => {
  const ast = esprima.parse(code);
  const args = ast.body[0].expression.arguments;
  return args.some(({value, type}) =>
       type === 'Literal'
    && typeof value === 'string'
    && value.includes('MATCH'));
};

console.log(matcher(`get(1101,"MATCH",obj)`));
console.log(matcher(`get(255,'NO MATCH',obj)`));
console.log(matcher(`get(1111,"" , MATCH)`));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esprima@~4.0/dist/esprima.js"></script>
```